# What is the hold called that forces the thighs apart in opposite directions from the pelvis?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, joint-lock, submissions

What is the submission called that forces the thighs apart from the pelvis in opposite directions?

Answer (score 6):

I imagine you are referring to wrestling's [banana split](https://fanaticwrestling.com/blogs/news/banana-split-wrestling-move).

Answer (score 1):

Yes that would be a "Banana Split".

There is also the "Croch Ripper"; difference is where the knees are pointing.

If they point away from each other, its an banana split.
If thes point at the same direction, its a crotch ripper.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MyQfzMiFZwM